# HTML textarea: How to display text with newline, spacing?

Tags: html, textarea, newline

I have a 'pre-populated' text area, where I want something in the order of:

```
Hi, enter some text here
    And press submit:)
```

(Just as example, I know it sounds stupid)
...To be displayed on page load. If I enter it verbatim in the HTML it displays as:

```
Hi, enter some text here

And press submit:)
```

Any ideas? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a tab in there

```
$val = "Hi, enter some text here \n \tAnd press submit:)"; //adds a newline and tab
```

And your HTML

```
<textarea>
<?php echo $val ?>
</textarea>
```

You might have to modify this a bit by adding placeholders if you want the tab characters to appear in different places.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just to explain things further, why is it that when \n and \t are used in HTML they are just printed, but when echoed through PHP they get parsed? Any way to get around the HTML literal printing? Thanks.

Comment: \n and \t have special meaning in PHP and actually puts the equivalent line feed or tab in there. HTML on the other hand completely ignores whitespace so you can't actually put it in there without having a bunch of nbsp